# only select columns of the a psql table could receive data

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jdbc

Something very bizarre have been happening. I have a very simple Entity recipe like so

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "recipe", schema = "public")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Recipe {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY
    )
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "instructions")
    private String instructions;
    @Column(name = "date_added", nullable = false)
    private String dateAdded;
    @Column(name = "last_edited", nullable = false)
    private String lastEdited;
}
```

and I have this post service that should post the 4 string attribute to the database

```
    public void postRecipe(Recipe recipe){
        var sql = """
                INSERT INTO public.recipe ("name","instructions","date_added","last_edited")
                VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
                """;
        jdbcTemplate.update(
                sql,
                recipe.getName(),
                recipe.getInstructions(),
                recipe.getDateAdded(),
                recipe.getLastEdited()
        );
    }
```

However when the following jason is sent using postman, I get the null value error.

```
{
    "name":"test", 
    "instructions":"don't eat",
    "date_added":"03/04/2017",
    "last_edited":"03/04/2017"
}
```

```
ERROR: null value in column \"date_added\" of relation \"recipe\" violates not-null constraint\n  Detail: Failing row contains (3, null, don't eat, null, test)
```

The strangest thing is that only the "name" and "instruction" columns receive their data and not the other columns. I have tried adding another String attribute to the Entity class and it also cannot get data from the jason.

[image: the columns of the database]

Edit 1:
I have tried adding the data directly through pgadmin and it worked fine

```
INSERT INTO recipe (name, instructions, date_added, last_edited)
VALUES ('test', 'test instruction', '2020/03/05', '2020/05/08');
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your deserialization is broken - transforming your JSON into the Java entity, which results in some null values present. Most likely because `date_added` != `dateAdded` (field name), and Jackson cannot properly set a value.

I recommend having a look at Jackson guide: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations, `@JsonProperty` specifically. And overall do not mix entities and [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)s

Comment: I will certainly look into adding DTO to my project although I don't think that's the issue here since the attributes are annotated with @column

Comment: yeah, it's not the issue, but it's a good practice to use DTOs. can you add @JsonProperty to the fields and try again?

Comment: It seems that changing ```@Column``` to ```@Jasonproperties``` also work. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: because you insert explicitly, so your `@Column` does not play a big role; if you used Hibernate/JPA for saving entities, then `@Column` would help to map columns correctly

Comment: could you elaborate on that a little bit more

Comment: I think you problem is with deserialization and not database at all, can you make a breakpoint before save and see which values are present in `recipe`?

Answer (score 0):

After many trials and errors I was able to come up with a solution but still have no clue as to why this is happening. It turns out the under score in the annotation is the problem.

```
//won't work
@Column(name = date_added)
//works
@Column(name = dateadded)
```

[image]

This is pretty strange because I am fairly certain that the under score is generated by hibernate.
if anyone know why this is happening please let me know... for now I will just stay away from the under scrolls.